Selecting single data point from navigator, combined column should stretch fully
I have combined column with navigator. And selecting single data point from navigator, column should stretch fully but pointPadding is not allowing to auto stretch combined column. And if pointPadding gets removed then column loosing the astethic that I don't want.
Expectations: combined column should auto stretch when select single data point from navigator if there is space between two data points while keep the astethic and design same.This is specific requirements that i have.


const COLUMN_CHART_DATA = {
  "profit": [
    [
      1714521600000,
      17257
    ],
    [
      1714608000000,
      36860
    ],
    [
      1714694400000,
      13384
    ],
    [
      1714780800000,
      21280
    ],
    [
      1714867200000,
      20402
    ],
    [
      1714953600000,
      17162
    ],
    [
      1715040000000,
      26282
    ],
    [
      1715126400000,
      6721
    ],
    [
      1715212800000,
      4473
    ],
    [
      1715299200000,
      24980
    ]
  ],
  "expectedProfit": [
    [
      1714521600000,
      39090
    ],
    [
      1714608000000,
      19133
    ],
    [
      1714694400000,
      1591
    ],
    [
      1714780800000,
      22355
    ],
    [
      1714867200000,
      38736
    ],
    [
      1714953600000,
      20744
    ],
    [
      1715040000000,
      2144
    ],
    [
      1715126400000,
      35585
    ],
    [
      1715212800000,
      9670
    ],
    [
      1715299200000,
      7604
    ]
  ],
  "revenue": [
    [
      1714521600000,
      9992
    ],
    [
      1714608000000,
      15572
    ],
    [
      1714694400000,
      37455
    ],
    [
      1714780800000,
      15766
    ],
    [
      1714867200000,
      27397
    ],
    [
      1714953600000,
      32429
    ],
    [
      1715040000000,
      35957
    ],
    [
      1715126400000,
      38172
    ],
    [
      1715212800000,
      8448
    ],
    [
      1715299200000,
      36733
    ]
  ],
  "expectedRevenue": [
    [
      1714521600000,
      15521
    ],
    [
      1714608000000,
      8368
    ],
    [
      1714694400000,
      3045
    ],
    [
      1714780800000,
      18400
    ],
    [
      1714867200000,
      22769
    ],
    [
      1714953600000,
      26957
    ],
    [
      1715040000000,
      5403
    ],
    [
      1715126400000,
      25348
    ],
    [
      1715212800000,
      9943
    ],
    [
      1715299200000,
      8287
    ]
  ]
};

const LINE_CHART_DATA = {
  seatFactor: [
    [
      1714521600000,
      266
    ],
    [
      1714608000000,
      177
    ],
    [
      1714694400000,
      311
    ],
    [
      1714780800000,
      312
    ],
    [
      1714867200000,
      409
    ],
    [
      1714953600000,
      440
    ],
    [
      1715040000000,
      305
    ],
    [
      1715126400000,
      317
    ],
    [
      1715212800000,
      453
    ],
    [
      1715299200000,
      433
    ]
  ],
  showUp: [
    [
      1714521600000,
      216
    ],
    [
      1714608000000,
      127
    ],
    [
      1714694400000,
      261
    ],
    [
      1714780800000,
      262
    ],
    [
      1714867200000,
      359
    ],
    [
      1714953600000,
      390
    ],
    [
      1715040000000,
      255
    ],
    [
      1715126400000,
      267
    ],
    [
      1715212800000,
      403
    ],
    [
      1715299200000,
      383
    ]
  ],
}

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
  },
  stockTools: {
    gui: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  navigator: {
    type: 'datetime',
    minRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // 1 day
    series: {
      type: 'column'
    }
  },
  xAxis: [{
    minRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Employees'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Profit (millions)'
    },
    opposite: false
  }],
  legend: {
    shadow: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false,
      shadow: false,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Curr LY',
      data: COLUMN_CHART_DATA.expectedProfit,
      color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
      pointPadding: 0.4,
      pointPlacement: -0.065,
    },
    {
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Curr',
      data: COLUMN_CHART_DATA.profit,
      color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
      pointPadding: 0.4,
      pointPlacement: -0.065,
    },
    {
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Final LY',
      data: COLUMN_CHART_DATA.expectedRevenue,
      pointPadding: 0.4,
      pointPlacement: 0.065,
      color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
    },
    {
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Exp',
      data: COLUMN_CHART_DATA.revenue,
      pointPadding: 0.4,
      pointPlacement: 0.065,
      color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
    },
    {
      type: "line",
      animation: false,
      name: "Seat Factor",
      data: LINE_CHART_DATA.seatFactor,
      color: '#E89306',
      yAxis: 1,
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: " / 10",
      },
    },
    {
      type: "line",
      animation: false,
      name: "Show up",
      data: LINE_CHART_DATA.showUp,
      color: '#C83828',
      yAxis: 1,
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: " / 10",
      },
    },
  ]
});
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/stocktools/gui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css">


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/indicators-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations-advanced.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/price-indicator.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/full-screen.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/stock-tools.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/heikinashi.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/hollowcandlestick.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>



JSFiddle Link

Hi, could you please clarify what you mean by a combined column and how do you select one point from navigator? Based on your code, I am not able to pick only one point. I am also not sure about the expected output. Would you be able to provide an example image of that?

Thanks @magdalena for quicky response. Okay, Forget about selecting 1 data point from the navigator range. Check this shared playground code https://jsfiddle.net/rwm34znb/ I want this behaviour exactly. When the navigator narrows down then the column should stretch. In OP it stretches very less and leaves so much space between two data points.

Anyone please! I'm waiting for solution.

Hi, @Umesh Codewalnut , apologize for the late responce. In that case set groupPadding to 0 and adjust pointPadding and pointPlacement options. Here is an example demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qyp026bs/
